# Watcher fails with class 'FileSystemEvent' can't be extended in build runner

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to run build runner in flutter I am getting this error and build runner is failing.

```
Watcher fails with class 'FileSystemEvent' can't be extended
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally got a solution.

`dart pub upgrade` worked for me.

Here is a [github](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/52570) issue for a reference.